Unscented Kalman filter Large Eroor convariance Matrix
i have been trying for a while to implement unscented kalman filter for state estimation
i have 4 states and 2 measurements,in there is a linear relaitonship between measurement(2) with states 3 and state 4
measurement(2)=x(3)+x(4)
there is no issue whenever i tried with only one states like for
measurement(2)=x(3) or measurement(2)=x(4)
but whenever i add both of them a large co variance matrix is generated like the below figure.
i have tried a few tuning method like tuning the process and measurement covariance matrix, but facing the same issue.
what would be reasons behind this large number of error covariance matrix?
I think i have some issue in State transition Model ( i used the continuous state transition model) is it can be reason?

You can check few things:

Ensure that x(2) and x(3) are observable. Covariance matrix will increase if either of these two states are un-observable.
Check state transition matrix and state-to-measurement matrix.
To help further, please share with us the equations of motion and measurements.

